# Cannot convert value of DataGridViewCell to double

Tags: c#, datagridview, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a value of a DataGridViewCell to a double value. I found out that cells are of type object. I tried to convert it directly from object to double an then from object to string to double, but it always multiplies values that contain a comma by 10. This is my code:

```
double d = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
```

or

```
string s = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
double d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
```

Comment: What's your decimal separator?

Comment: What value does it contain `s`?

Comment: I am using "," as a decimal separator. I set the separator in the Excel workbook from where the datagridview is filled with to ".", but it did not work either.

Comment: s contains e.g. 3,5 , but the d is 35 then

Comment: You must check the regional configuration of your computer language, and verify if the decimal separator is set with a  `,` or a `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always pass the `IFormatProvider` when converting strings to numbers. The server your site will run might have a different culture setting.

```
Convert.ToDouble(s, new CultureInfo("your-culture").NumberFormat);
```